# how to I triggered jqueryDatePicker

Tags: angularjs

hello all i am stuck in a problem if any body has a solution please guide me on that.
basically i want to triggered event of jqueryDatePicker and get the selected date on clicking on any date.
I search but didn't get the solution.
It is done in AngularJs.
below is my code

```
  <div id="txtfuturedateWeekly" ng-model="employee.Date" jqdatepicker></div>


app.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element) {
        $element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
            onSelect: function (date) {
               $scope.date = date;
               $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

and i want to call a below function to be fire when date is selected

```
  function lastDate(date) {

    var lDate = date
    var myDate = new Date(lDate );       

}
```

[image]

```
function lastDate(date) {
    debugger;
    var lDate = $scope.employee.Date;//document.getElementById('datepicker').value;// see how to fetch value
    var myDate = new Date(lDate);

    var startOfWeek = moment(myDate).startOf('isoweek').toDate();
    var tue = moment(startOfWeek).add(1, 'days').toDate();
    var wed = moment(startOfWeek).add(2, 'days').toDate();
    var thu = moment(startOfWeek).add(3, 'days').toDate();
    var fri = moment(startOfWeek).add(4, 'days').toDate();
    var sat = moment(startOfWeek).add(5, 'days').toDate();
    var endOfWeek = moment(myDate).endOf('isoweek').toDate();

    var monDay = moment(startOfWeek).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var tueDay = moment(tue).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var wedDay = moment(wed).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var thuDay = moment(thu).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var friDay = moment(fri).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var satDay = moment(sat).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var sunDay = moment(endOfWeek).format("DD/MM/YYYY");

    $scope.employee.day1 = monDay;
    $scope.employee.day2 = tueDay;
    $scope.employee.day3 = wedDay;
    $scope.employee.day4 = thuDay;
    $scope.employee.day5 = friDay;
    $scope.employee.day6 = satDay;
    $scope.employee.day7 = sunDay;

    $scope.employee.Date = monDay;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how everything is wired up. `lastDate` looks like a controller, but $scope isn't being injected and neither is moment. I thought you wanted to call the function `lastDate` on change. What you're showing me here is `lastDate` as the controller, instead of being a function on the controller's scope like I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I think you can do something like this:

```
app.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
           ngModel: '=',
           ngChange: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                   scope.$apply(function() {
                      scope.ngModel = date;
                      if(scope.ngChange) {
                         scope.ngChange(date);
                      }
                   });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then in your html (assuming you have `lastDate()` on the scope):

```
<div ng-model="employee.Date" jqdatepicker ng-change="lastDate(employee.Date)"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, give this new version a try

Comment: hello @DerekMT12 basically on apply input of type textbox then the code is working but using div tag as shown above it not triggered ng-change event

Comment: Can you show me the controller code where `lastDate` is?

Comment: i add it above just see